# How to make blur effect when a div overlays another HTML element?

Tags: css, stylus

I want to make certain `div`s have a blur filter so when they are on other elements on the website, their backgrounds become blurry images of the elements.

Preferably in Stylus.

Apple uses this on their [Apple TV website](https://www.apple.com/tv/) as shown below:

[image: Apple TV Web Blur Example]

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to target Latest Safari browser, you can use the `backdrop-filter` introduced to `webkit`.

```
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
```

But remember that it currently works only in Safari latest versions. As you can see **[here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter)**.

To learn more visit this **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)** link.

**Update:**

You can use this following trick to create the effect for other browsers. Note that it will not work if you want to make only part of the backdrop blur.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.backdrop {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.backdrop img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">This is just an overlay</div>
</div>
```

**Update 2:**

A dirty but working way of creating the `backdrop-filter` effect in browsers other than Safari. **This will work only in case the background is an `img`**. I used `jQuery` to attain the goal.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  bgWidth = $('.backdrop img').outerWidth();
  bgLeft = $('.backdrop img').offset().left - $('.overlay').offset().left;
  bgTop = $('.backdrop img').offset().top - $('.overlay').offset().top;
  bg = $('.backdrop img').prop('src');

  //console.log($('.backdrop img').offset().top, $('.overlay').offset().top)

  $('.overlay .blury').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + bg + ')',
    'background-size': bgWidth + 'px auto',
    'background-position': (bgLeft) + 'px ' + (bgTop) + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.backdrop img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.overlayText, .overlay .blury {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.overlayText{
  z-index:2;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.overlay .blury {
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
  z-index:1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlayText">This is just an overlay</div>
    <div style="" class="blury"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```